# Inverse Wishart

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Assume that $X\sim \operatorname{IW}_p(n,\Sigma)$ has an inverse Wishart distribution, which  probability density function is
$$f(X\mid n,\Sigma)=C(n,\Sigma)|X|^{-\frac{n+p+1}{2}} \exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}(\Sigma X^{-1})\Big), \tag 1$$
where $C(n,\Sigma)$ is a constant, only depends on $n$ and $\Sigma.$

Partition the matrices $X$   and $\Sigma$ conformably with each other
$$X=\pmatrix{X_{11}&X_{12}\\X_{21}&X_{22}},~~\Sigma=\pmatrix{\Sigma_{11}&\Sigma_{12}\\\Sigma_{21}&\Sigma_{22}}.$$
where $X_{ij}$ and $\Sigma_{ij}$ are $p_i\times p_j$ matrices.

How to prove $X_{11}\sim \operatorname{IW}(n-p_2,\Sigma_{11})$, by the probability density function of $X$ in (1) directly, not the definition of $\operatorname{IW}$ or Wishart distribution???

Comment: this would be rather surprising if you proved something about $IW$ without even using its definition.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik : I'm guessing the poster meant how do you prove it by using the density function on line $(1),$ without using anything about sums of products of certain random matrices.

Comment: Might you have meant $X_{11} \sim \operatorname{IW}_{p_1}(n, \Sigma_{11}) \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: A pdf is always with respect to some measure. Which measure in this case? How can one integrate? Is it just $$ \int f(x) \prod_{i,\,j} dx_{i,j} $$ over the whole space of positive-definite matrices $x$, where $x_{i,j}$ is the $i,j$ entry in $x$? That would mean Lebesgue measure $dx_{i,j}$ on each entry, and the bounds of integration would be --- complicated. This needs some explanation. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy Yes.  $\int f(x) \prod_{i,j} dx_{i,j}$. I want to know how to prove it by using the density function on the line (1), without using anything about sums of products of certain random matrices.

Comment: @XiaopaiSong : I still suspect you need $X_{11} \sim \operatorname{IW}_{p_1} (n,\Sigma_{11}). \qquad$

Comment: @ Michael Hardy I found it from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution.

Comment: Such a result is proved in Gupta & Nagar's book *Matrix variate distributions* (they use a different definition of the inverse-Wishart distribution but the difference lies in the parameterization only).

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent Thanks.